# XAML to XHTML Converter

Tags: silverlight, xaml, xhtml, seo

I find this article interesting for the work around of a full silverlight website

> http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-SEO.aspx#comment1875

I want to know how to convert XAML to XHTML

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to convert "any" XAML to XHTML, because (for exemple) the layout is not done the same way in XAML and in XHTML.

In fact, as Silverlight allows developpers to build custom controls and rather complicated View Trees which you won't be able to get with XAML alone. Animation and Control States (and dynamic display) will prevent you further to achieve anything generic.

But you can easily do something not generic at all with a known XAML subset.

For instance, you could use the XAML generated by the Silverlight RichTextBox and transform it to SEO compatible XHTML with a rather simple XSLT style Sheet. As this XAML has the same structure as any XHTML content, it isn't especially complicated.

You won't output beautiful XHTML texts, but it can be enough. You could output Text, simple CSS attributes and br/span/p tags.